Trino hive to iceberg table migration without data move
I have a trino setup on EMR with hive and iceberg configured to use AWS glue as the catalog. There is a hive table created like this.
CREATE SCHEMA hive.schema1 WITH (location = 's3://bucket1/schema1')")
CREATE TABLE hive.schema1.table1
                (
                    ...
                    FieldDate   DATE
                )
                WITH (
                    format = 'PARQUET',
                    partitioned_by = ARRAY['FieldDate']
                )
            

Then import the data from hive table to iceberg table using below.
CREATE SCHEMA iceberg.schema2 WITH (location = 's3://bucket2/schema2')"
CREATE TABLE iceberg.schema2.table2
                WITH (
                    format='PARQUET',
                    partitioning=ARRAY['day(FieldDate)'],
                    location='s3://bucket2/schema2/table2'
                )
                AS
                SELECT 
                    ...
                    FieldDate
                FROM hive.schema1.table1
            

Is it possible to create an iceberg table using the hive table without moving/copying data in s3?

Please check out spark iceberg procedures documentation to migrate hive tables to iceberg with in place or shadow migration.
You can use either snapshot, register , migrate or add_files procedure of spark or trino
https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#table-migration
https://www.dremio.com/blog/migrating-a-hive-table-to-an-iceberg-table-hands-on-tutorial/
